AntD: remove dropdown from SubMenuItem
In my application, I have a menu like this:
const items = {
        key: "product-locations",
        icon: <Icon name="map-02" />,
        label: "Product Locations"
      },
{
        key: "product-manage",
        icon: <Icon name="map-03" />,
        label: "Product Manage",
        children: [
          {
            key: "locations",
            label: (
              <Link className="flex" to="/product-locations/locations">
                Regions
              </Link>
            ),
          },
        ],
      }

and my menu looked like this:
<Menu
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          defaultOpenKeys={collapsed ? [] : selectedKeys}
          mode="inline"
          items={items}
          inlineCollapsed={collapsed}
        />

The problem here is the style of product-locations and product-manage is inconsistent (one is submenuitem, the other is menuitem).
I tried to change the product-locations have children=[] to make it become submenuitem but now I have to remove the drop down icon.
So my question is: Is there anyway to remove the dropdown from submenuitem?
